# Scrapyd Deploy Error: EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I have 2 pc, PC A doesn't have errors and crawlers are deployed successfully, but on PC B, the error happens.

My Scrapyd server is running but then when I tried to deploy my crawlers, these error occurs.

`{"status": "error", "message":Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 162, in _run_module_as_main\\n    \"__main__\", fname, loader, pkg_name)\\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\\n    exec code in run_globals\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 40, in <module>\\n    main()\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py\", line 37, in main\\n    execute()\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py\", line 148, in execute\\n    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py\", line 243, in __init__\\n    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py\", line 134, in __init__\\n    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py\", line 330, in _get_spider_loader\\n    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py\", line 61, in from_settings\\n    return cls(settings)\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py\", line 25, in __init__\\n    self._load_all_spiders()\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py\", line 47, in _load_all_spiders\\n    for module in walk_modules(name):\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py\", line 71, in walk_modules\\n    submod = import_module(fullpath)\\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py\", line 37, in import_module\\n    __import__(name)\\n  File \"spiderman/spiders/scraper.py\", line 16, in <module>\\n    mail = input('Email : ')\\nEOFError: EOF when reading a line\\n", "node_name": "MY PC"}`

Comment: Please format the error trace and also provide source code for the spider (namely `scraper.py` according to the message).

Comment: you have error on line 16 in file spiderman/spiders/scraper.py

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the next packages:

- apt-get update
- apt-get install gcc
- apt-get install python-dev
- pip install scrapyd
- pip install scrapyd-client
- pip install beautifulsoup4
- pip install dateparser

And try to deploy again